# Bias-Variance Bulls-Eye Diagram: high variance and high bias

Tags: overfitting, bias

Often bias/variance trade-off is explained by a [Bulls eye diagram](https://towardsdatascience.com/what-bias-variance-bulls-eye-diagram-really-represent-ff6fb9670993). I like the explanation in the linked webpage but it doesn't answer the question how a model that has high variance **and** high bias would look like. Must be some type of wrongly created / invalid model? e.g. high order polynom that uses a wrong intercept? Is there a more general answer?